# Oozie workflow: is it possible to get environment variable value through EL function

Tags: shell, environment-variables, el, oozie

I am Oozie currently, is it possible to get value of environment variable in the workflow.xml by means of EL function?

Answer (score 0):

per "http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html" it appears you can do get it out, but i tried i could not get the value out as one of the jar which uses the class_path still complains missing class.